# Laravel 9: after success login systems will log out immediately

Tags: php, laravel

I've created new guard for Admins in my Laravel 9 project.

Then I want to log in returns me true at that time, but it's log me out immediately

here is my admin model :

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, Notifiable, InteractsWithMedia, HasScopeWatcher;

    protected $guard = "admin";

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone',
        'national_code'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'full_name',
        'avatar'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
```

Here Is auth.php :

```
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admin',
        'passwords' => 'admins',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins'
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api-experts' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'experts',
        ]
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        'experts' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Expert::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

   

];
```

Here are my routes :

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check()); // after I call /login this route returns me false
});
Route::get('/login',function(){
    Auth::guard('admin')->loginUsingId(1);
    dd(auth('admin')->check()); // Returns Me true
});
```

I also try Both
`Auth::guard('admin')->attempt()`
and
`Auth::guard('admin')->loginUsingId(1);`
both result are same.

And also I tried to change my session driver to database but again same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.env` I've changed `SESSION_DRIVER` to cookie and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The response with the proper cookies to set the needed values to identify the admin for the next request(s) is not sent when you "dump and die" `dd()`

Just remove it

```php
Route::get('/',function(){
    dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check()); // after I call /login this route returns me false
});
Route::get('/login',function(){
    Auth::guard('admin')->loginUsingId(1);
    // remove this dd() so a response with the proper encrypted cookies gets to the client side
});
```

Comment: I've just put `dd()` for test, even without "dump and die" again every thing is the same

Comment: @ArashPourebrahimi I just tested it locally and it worked once the `dd()` was removed.